# inheritance is not working in react mocha test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js

I have used the below structure to create a react component which is working on the browser after done babel. But the Layout spec is failing in my case since the `React` is declared in `Base` component only. Why the inheritance is not working in spec?

**Base.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Base extends React.Component {

}
```

**Layout.js**

```
import 'Base' from './Base';

export default class Layout extends Base {
const sample = React.cloneElement(this.props.data, {ref: 't'});

}
```

**Test Case**

```
import Layout from 'component/Layout'
import React from 'react';

describe('Layout', () => {
}
```

**Error message:**

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React
```

Answer (score 2):

In *Layout.js* you have the following line

```
const sample = React.cloneElement(this.props.data, {ref: 't'});
```

Here you reference `React`, but *Layout.js* hasn't got a definition for `React`, similar to how you don't have access to identifiers in different closures, so it would throw a *ReferenceError*

If you want to use this reference you need to first teach it to *Layout.js* by including the `import` line again

```
import React from 'react';
```

If you don't want to have a second import line, you could

1. Re-export `React` in *Base.js* so the one import does both `import {foo, bar} from 'baz';`
2. See if you can reference what you want *through* an identifier you can see, e.g. via `Object.getPrototypeOf(Base.prototype).constructor`?

---

<strike>As you are creating `React` as a global in *Test Case*, the ReferenceError in mocha may be getting thrown too early, moving the `import React` line above the `import Layout` line should fix this</strike>

Comment: Thx. Yeah I know it. If I'm add the React reference in Layout It'll work for test case. But the same configuration is working on browser and not working test level. Why the mocha is not getting the reference (React) from the inherited class 'Base'?

Comment: If it is working in your browser, is `React` a _global_ in your browser?

Comment: Yes. Is there any way to define React as a global for testcase?

Comment: @Mr.Black Maybe Mocha is throwing the error early; try moving `import Layout from 'component/Layout';` below the `React` import

Comment: I have already tried. It's not working. I'm getting same error.

Comment: @Mr.Black Bug in mocha? These are _new features_. I hope you find out. In the short term, if you just need this error message to disappear you can just add the extra `import`